# What does it mean for a framework to call you?

Tags: javascript, callback, frameworks

My goal is to fully understand the differences between a library and a framework

I have been able to have a basic understanding of the differences between the two. Except for one basic description that is commonly given out:

"The key difference between a library and a framework is "Inversion of Control". When you call a method from a library, you are in control. But with a framework, the control is inverted: the framework calls you"
[programcreek.com](https://www.programcreek.com/2011/09/what-is-the-difference-between-a-java-library-and-a-framework/)

What does it mean for a framework to call you?

I have done research on what it means to call a function, method, etc. and now have a full understanding... But I am not able to comprehend nor find any information on what it means for a framework to call you

I have tried looking this question up with multiple different ways to frame it and all I am able to find is: [MFC Framework how a framework calls your code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/how-the-framework-calls-your-code?view=vs-2019). I am not able to find anything in the realm of languages or frameworks I am familiar with

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I offer you to read [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article. you can search on google and read some medium articles or watch youtube videos and fully understand what is Framework and what the is Library. I hope my comment helps you to have a better experience on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the welcoming comment. I have read that article. May I ask what in particular stood out to you that makes it an improper question so that I may improve? Thank you

Comment: What does the title mean? are you confused by the meaning of framework or library? why your tags are the names of frontend libraries and frameworks? I guess you just wanted to leave a question. obviously it is not a good question by my sight.

Comment: Basically if you look up framework vs library, one of the number one distinctions is that a Framework calls your code. Whereas a library is called by you. I would still like to continue to make this question acceptable

Comment: A library can call you too. The difference use in usage and architecture, and there isn't always a clear delineation between the two. But who calls who isn't really relevant at all. There's no way to salvage this question on SO, a different SE site might be more appropriate--SO is oriented toward actual code, not ambiguous definitions.

Comment: Regarding "what does it mean for a framework (or library) to call you"--it means exactly what it says: code that isn't yours called your code. This happens all the time in both frameworks and libraries.

Comment: Thank you Dave Newton. I will sit on some of the things you have mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguably **any sufficiently complete library is indistinguishable from a framework.** By inversion, any sufficiently thin framework can be treated like a library.

In simple terms, the more a library dictates how you code, what practices and conventions to follow, and how to organize your code, the more it resembles a framework.

The "inversion of control" is something that doesn't necessarily happen in a clean-cut way. Some frameworks are very light in that they don't force a lot on you, that you can yield control incrementally. Others dictate strict terms, that you either do it their way or you don't do it at all.

There's a huge spectrum here of framework-like-libraries and library-like-frameworks.

When a framework "calls" your code, it usually means that you've followed the patterns laid out by the framework itself and your code slots into pre-defined locations in that pattern.

That's not to say libraries don't call your code as well, they just impose fewer constraints on where, when and how that happens.

So here's a library call:

```
// Tell the library to perform a user registration
let user = FancyLibrary.registerUser(...);
```

Here's a framework-like structure:

```
// Start up the framework and ask for notifications if/when a particular event occurs
let app = new SuperFramework({
   onRegistration: user => { ... }
});
```

Though there's often a blurry line here. Some situations are very clear, but there's a lot of toolkits that have strong conventions, even if they are libraries.

For an example of something that's sort of in the middle, consider [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/v5/) which is an ORM. Is it a framework? Most would consider an ORM to be similar to that, it has strong conventions and so on, but it's also a library that can be used to make simple SQL calls, nothing more. It's hard to say exactly what Sequelize is other than a robust toolkit that can be used to perform complex tasks.

Comment: I wish I could upvote. Thank you very, very much

Comment: Dear @tadmna, I guess answering questions like this which are not very acceptable on SO is not a good act. It's your opinion to answer anythings but if attention to the question two other users and I leave close flag to this post. Also, I leave a downvote and `very-low-quality` flag for your answer because I think this question should be closed now and will delete in the near future. I hope do not get upset.

Comment: This question is closed and was resolved. What can I do to make this question of higher quality?

Comment: It's not necessarily the quality of the question, but the nature of it, as Stack Overflow has a fairly narrow focus and a lot of things are off-topic. Here we're generally talking about broken code, not hypotheticals. For more abstract questions, consider [Quora](https://www.quora.com).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! my bad